# Create jar(library) of android framework for ICS

Tags: android, frameworks

I want to create jar (Library) file of android frameworks library for ice cream sandwhich. Is it possible? Please give me any idea related to it.

Comment: What do you mean by _android frameworks library_ ?

Comment: @user603125 i want to create phone app for ICS so i want framework's library, so can you share idea if you have ! thanks

Comment: You can download the ICS sdk using the Android SDK manager, if thats what you mean?